# How do I get the value of the argument in argument.nameOfTheMethod()?

Tags: java, methods

How can I get the value of the Argument to implement such a method. `argument.nameOfTheMethod()`.
I want to use a condition on this argument to write the code of this method.

For example:

```
"foo".charAt()
```

How does `charAt` access the value of `"foo"`?

Comment: `"foo"` is an object of class `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `"foo".CharAt()` How does `charAt` access the value of `"foo"`?

`charAt` accesses the value `"foo"` through the `this` reference inside the method.

When calling `obj.method()` you can see `obj` as an implicit argument with name `this`. In Java 8 you can even make it explicit in the method signature as follows:

```
class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(SomeClass this) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's a good starting point: [The Java™ Tutorials: Using the `this` Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: Source of using this as parameter name? I don't think this works, and it doesn't make much sense in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any source at hand. I'm a java compiler dev at Oracle, so you can take my post as source ;) I never said it makes sense to write it the way I did. It's just an example to illustrate how to access the receiver.

Comment: Ok, I dug it up. [JLS 8.4.1: Formal Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1). See *ReceiverParameter*.

Comment: @aioobe My mind is so blown right now. In multiple ways.

Comment: The first comment was already source enough, fellow compiler dev :)